# System.InvalidOperationException on ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could you please advice me on what this error means:

> The ViewData item that has the key "Cat ID" is of type'System.Int32' but must be of type IEnumerble

I'm using entity framework

Comment: the error is specific to asp.net mvc, please post the relevant code

Comment: Check the message. It says that you tried to tread `Cat ID` as if it were an array or list

Comment: You've just passed one item into your `ViewData` and used it in the view with `foreach`, it should be a `IEnumerable` collection. #Sherlock

Comment: We need codes to understand your problem

Comment: What I have difficulty understanding is, why people take the burden of writing the error messages by hand instead of copying / pasting it. In the above error message, there are two obvious typos. Cases where the source code is re-written by hand is also not that rare. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You've just passed one item into your ViewData.In your case Viewdata has got list of items, so you should cast ViewData as a IEnumerable and then get the values from foreach loop.